# Disable Intellij IDEA hiding the sidebar on tab click

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij automatically hides the sidebar with my project files when I click on a tab. That is, I have multiple source files open in tabs on the top and on the left I have the tree view of my project files. This tree view, and any console on the bottom, gets hidden (so that the code fills the whole window) when I click on a tab and reappears when I click on the tab again.

This is annoying, can I disable that behavior? I haven't changed (or found) any relevant settings, that seems to be default behavior.

I am using 2016.2.5 on Ubuntu, but other versions show the same behavior.

Comment: This isn't IDEA's default behavior, it only does this on double-click. Do you maybe have a tiring mouse?